# How to pass a web socket handler instance instead of class

Tags: websocket, jetty

I'm working with embedded Jetty websockets and what I see in the examples is passing the Class of the handler to the container instead of an instance. I would to know if it's possible to pass an instance instead of a class and how that works.

```
ServerContainer wscontainer = webSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context);

// Add WebSocket endpoint to javax.websocket layer
wscontainer.addEndpoint(EventSocket.class);
```

I would like to be able to do

```
wscontainer.addEndpoint(new EventSocket());
```

of course this method is not supported.

I see that on the client side you can provide an instance of a handler

```
Session session = container.connectToServer(new ClientSocket(), uri);
```

I'm curious why the api was designed to accept a class instead of an instance, which is unlike how servlets work.

Update:

The following solution works:

```
        // contains ServerEndpoint annotation and onMessage, onOpen etc
        final EventSocket eventSocket = new EventSocket();

        ServerEndpointConfig config = ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create(eventSocket.getClass(), eventSocket.getClass().getAnnotation(ServerEndpoint.class).value())
                        .configurator(new Configurator() {
                            @Override
                            public <T> T getEndpointInstance(Class<T> endpointClass) throws InstantiationException {
                                return (T) eventSocket;
                            }                                 
                        })
                        .build();
        wscontainer.addEndpoint(config);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In servlets, you have 1 instance for all requests to the same servlet.

In a websocket server, you have long lived connections, and the normal technique is to have a new websocket endpoint instance per connection.  In websocket clients, you don't have to worry about this.  You are just 1 instance to start with.  If you want multiple connections, you have multiple instances of that websocket endpoint that you created yourself.

`ServerContainer` is a [`javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerContainer.html) (aka JSR-356).

It has 2 `addEndpoint()` mechanisms:

- [`addEndpoint(Class<?> endpointClass)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerContainer.html#addEndpoint(java.lang.Class)) assumes that the class either extends from [`Endpoint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Endpoint.html) or is annotated with [`@ServerEndpoint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html) (yes, you can have server that doesn't initialize via annotation scanning, but still uses annotations and this addEndpoint mechanism to programatically add endpoints).  It assumes that the server will instantiate a new Endpoint on each incoming websocket upgrade request.
- [`addEndpoint(ServerEndpointConfig serverConfig)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerContainer.html#addEndpoint(javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig)) takes a [`ServerEndpointConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.html) that declares how you want your endpoint to bound.  It too assumes that the server will instantiate a new Endpoint on each incoming websocket upgrade request.  However, there is way out using this technique.  Define your own [`Configurator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html) object that overrides the [`getEndpointInstance(Class<?> endpointClass)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#getEndpointInstance(java.lang.Class)) method, returning the same object over and over again.   Just note that the instance you return must be of the class type that was passed into that method (otherwise its an error).

If you choose to use the [jetty native websocket implementation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-server-api.html#d0e22020), then you can also use the [`WebSocketCreator`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/WebSocketCreator.html) to handle the creation of websocket instances, even singletons.

Comment: I've looked at those interfaces but it's unclear to me how to provide the ServerEndpointConfig implementation. Really I'd like to only override the getEndpointInstance method. I updated my question with an approach I tried however it did not work

Comment: Look at `ServerEndpointConfig.Builder` - [example usage](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/blob/184c060ea6088af46a2228656598e73ed8f50566/cometd-java/cometd-java-websocket/cometd-java-websocket-javax-server/src/main/java/org/cometd/websocket/server/WebSocketTransport.java#L93-L104)

Comment: Ok, yes that works. I had left off a trailing slash. I updated my question with the solution, getting the path from the annotation prevent mistakes. Thanks

Comment: I get your point about multiple instance of the endpoint but this could have been simplified by providing an interface that asks for a endpoint instance, given a class. Or just keep them thread-safe, like servlets. Just seems to be a fundamental need to wire up an endpoint with references, and not with statics.